# What's the touch resolution (LPI) of the Magic Trackpad?

Tags: multi-touch, magic-trackpad, adobe-photoshop, drawing

I'd like to know how the Magic Trackpad compares with Wacom tablets as far as resolution goes.  The Wacom Intuos5 line has 5080 LPI, while the Bamboo line has 2540.

Comment: I'd assume the Magic Trackpad would have a much lower resolution than the tablets you mentioned.  The Magic trackpad is designed to be used similarly to the trackpad on a macbook; used for web browsing, etc, and not for very fine drawing work like the Wacoms.